# Wordpress get_template_directory_uri() not returning https and only return http

Tags: php, wordpress, server, wordpress-theming

I install `ssl` on my site everything working fine except one thing, all the links coming from `get_template_directory_uri()` function are not returning `https` 
https://www.bearapeninsula.com here is a website link.

As you can see everything else is working fine but if you go on other pages and inspect it and check console you will see the mixed content errors which is because of `get_template_directory_uri()` not displaying `https`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the WordPress and Site Address URL under the general settings include **`https`**

[image]
*The image shows, `http`, you need `https`*

[`get_tample_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) uses the [`site_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/) , tacking on the name of your WordPress content directory, and the location of your theme plus its name. `site_url` will return `http` if [`is_ssl()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_ssl/) is false, which depends on your General Settings, as stated above.

Answer (score -1):

**get_template_directory_uri()** dosn't return full URL but only URI. To get website url, you can use **get_site_url()** function

Comment: Unless is_ssl() is returning true, this will still return `http`

Comment: it's relative to the website configuration

Comment: That means though, that it will still return non ssl unless the configuration is changed.

Comment: Exactly, so you should turn your website into `https`

Comment: Your answer doesn't address that at all.

Comment: after taking a look at the website, the mixed content does not come from your website but cdn links that are in http, you must replace them with `https` links or just `// url`

Replace `http://cdn.stumble-upon.com/js/badge_su.js?v=20120613` by `https://cdn.stumble-upon.com/js/badge_su.js?v=20120613` or just `//cdn.stumble-upon.com/js/badge_su.js?v=20120613` to avoid mixte content error. The wordpress config is OK